# Bot responds to every command if it has 2 letters in front of it

Tags: discord, discord.js

For example if the command with user input is `r!test`
then the bot will respond to `aatest` etc. as well
Is there a way to fix this issue?
I also tried command.startsWith('r!') didnt work bot didnt respond at all.
If you need it here is code

```js
    if(command === 'slap') {
      const taggedUser = msg.mentions.users.first();
      if (!msg.mentions.users.size) {
        const mentionisembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
          .setTitle('Slap')
          .setDescription('You cant slap nobody.')
        return msg.channel.send(mentionisembed);
      }
      gifSearch.random('slap').then(
        gifUrl =>{
          const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
          .setTitle('Slap')
          
          .setAuthor(taggedUser.username)
          .setDescription(`You slapped ${taggedUser.username}.`)
          .setImage(gifUrl)
          .setFooter('slapping idiots since 1972');
        msg.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
  
        }
    );

         
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```js
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
```

and not

```js
if(!message.startsWith(prefix)) return;
```

Since the message has many properties and it cannot be a string. I think you meant "content"

So write this at the biggining of your code. This way all messages that doesn't start with your prefix (you can replace the prefix variable with your actual prefix) will be ignored by the bot

Comment: I tried but now the bot doesnt respond at all
**edit: nvm that was just my bots lag**

Comment: lmfao ;'), i guess you can close the question and approuve this